# Bringing background activity to foreground after set time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, background, foreground

I'm making a scare app where after a user determined set amount of time( choosen by this button representing 15 seconds) a scary face will popup and will play a scream sound. I need the user to be able to leave to the home screen with it running in the background and have it come to the foreground after the set time.

The code below is the `onclicklistener` on the "15 sec" `Button`, it works perfectly on an emulator but never comes to the foreground when tested on a device.     `Switcher` is a switch view which changes to the scary face and sp.play is the sound.

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tick.setImageResource(R.drawable.blacktick);
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    switcher.showNext();
                    sp.play(Screamsp, 1, 1,0, 0, 1);    
                }
            }, 15000);


            tick.setImageResource(R.drawable.blacktick);

        }
    });
```

Comment: try to mark your activity in mainfest as singletop

Comment: No luck<activity
            android:name="com.scaretimebomb2.MainActivity"
             android:launchMode="singleTop"
            
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>